# Ubuntu. I have disabled ssh login with root on my server, but how to copy files from local to server now?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, scp

I can log in to my server with user name "xyzuser" and then use `su -l` to get root access.

But how do I transfer files?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why is the [tag:apache] tag here? You never mention Apache in the question. Why doesn't `scp foo bar baz xyzuser@ubuntu_host:/foo/bar` work?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an ftp server, you can upload the files through ftp.

You could use an NFS share too - it's easy to setup with a /etc/exports file.

If your server runs Windows, you can have a Samba server setup with a shared folder or connect to a shared folder using smbclient.

You could host your files on your local web server and have the server 'pull' the file using wget.